# Slow IIS on local Windows 10 PC

Tags: iis

I've been running IIS over the years, on Windows 2000, Windows XP and Windows 7.

Since I moved to Windows 10, I've been having lots of problems with IIS running slowly.

I have a clean install of Windows 10 on my PC, not a previous Win7 version upgraded to Windows 10.

These are the versions:

```
Windows 10 Version 1511 (OS Build 10586.420)
Internet Information Services (Version 10.0.10586.0)
```

I have tried all sorts to fix this issue, such as editing my hosts file to this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Or commenting that line out.

I've tried running as:

127.0.0.1/mysite instead of localhost/mysite

I've tried tweaking various settings on the ApplicationPool, as per reading I've done on StackOverflow and the web in general.

There is nothing in the Event Log to do with errors or problems being flagged up.

However, a lot of the time page refreshes take over 1 minute to complete, which makes local development very slow.

The issue is the same on Chrome, Firefox, IE and Edge browsers.

Comment: How does that 1 minute break down? Have you taken gotten any tools to see where the 1 minute come from? Try using Telerik's Fiddler.

Comment: @Aron Fiddler at browser side might not be that helpful alone. If the questioner can also enable Failed Request Tracing on IIS side, then he/she can get more details on the time break down inside IIS.

Comment: @OP, did you solve it?

Comment: @Bartosz I did solve it, but I have no idea how :-( very silly of me sorry. I thought it was to do with Application Pools but it doesn't seem to be. If I find out I'll update this answer. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

I just re-installed Windows 10 and had the same issue again.

My IIS files sit outside of the wwwroot folder, in the `c:\data` folder. The localhost site was running painfully slow again.

This time, I fixed it by giving Read access to `IUSR`, `NETWORK SERVICE` and `IIS_IUSR` when right-clicking the folder and going to Properties > Permissions - e.g. for `NETWORK SERVICE`:

[image]

After that I restarted the IIS server and it sped up a lot.

This isn't how I fixed it last time though, but I can't remember how I fixed it them - so putting in this fix this time before I forget it!